Запуск сервера базы данных
Сейчас я разрабатываю сайт на Python с SQLAlchemy. При этом использую диалект postgresql. Сама база данных локальная на моём компьютере, соответственно другие люди к ней подключиться не могут. Подскажите какие существуют методики для разработки базы данных с командой разработчиков? Как можно запустить сервер с базой данных и при этом подключиться с другого компьютера? Премного благодарен) P.S. Установлена виртуальная ОС Ubuntu server.

Белый ip можешь купить у своего провайдера? Ну или хостинг.

Как вариант можно

Ну значит делай. Это наиболее лайтовые варианты в твоём случае. Можно и через ipv6, но это для джедаев.

Настройка PostgreSQL для удаленного доступа:
Отредактируй файл postgresql.conf:
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/<версия PostgreSQL>/main/postgresql.conf
Найди и измени параметр listen_addresses:
listen_addresses = '*'
Затем отредактируй файл pg_hba.conf для разрешения доступа:
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/<версия PostgreSQL>/main/pg_hba.conf
Добавь следующую строку в конец файла для разрешения доступа (замени X.X.X.X/32 на нужный IP-адрес или диапазон):
host    all             all             X.X.X.X/32            md5
Открытие портов на сервере: (ufw) (по умолчанию 5432):
sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp
Перезапуск PostgreSQL: После внесения изменений перезапусти PostgreSQL
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
Создание пользователя и бд: Войди в интерактивную оболочку PostgreSQL:
sudo -u postgres psql
Внутри оболочки создай пользователя и базу данных:
CREATE USER новый_пользователь WITH PASSWORD 'пароль';
CREATE DATABASE новая_база_данных OWNER новый_пользователь;

Выход: \q

Ну а про белый ip и port forwarding где?

Спасибо за ответ на вопрос. А можете подсказать, вообще возможна ли разработка с использованием локальных баз в совокупности с миграциями? Чтобы не использовать удалённый доступ
и для общей осведомлённости... что такое белый ip?)

Ну блин, погугли "что такое белый ip".
